# (Django) 'CommentView' object has no attribute 'body'

Tags: python, django, httpie

I have been trying to emulate comment functionality with a decorator.

```
import json
import jwt

from django.views           import View
from django.http            import JsonResponse
from functools              import wraps
from django.db.models       import Q

from .models                    import Comment
from account.models   import Account

class CommentView(View):


    def login_required(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            given_token     = json.loads(request.body)['access_token']
            decoded_token   = jwt.decode(given_token,None,None)
            try:
                if Account.objects.filter(username=decoded_token).exists():
                    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                return JsonResponse({"message": "username does not exist"})
            except KeyError:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "INVALID_KEYS"}, status=403)
        return wrapper



    @login_required
    def post(self, request):
        print("request ", json.loads(request.body))
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        Comment.objects.create(
                username    = jwt.decode(json.loads(request.body)['access_token']),
                content     = data['content'],
        )
        return JsonResponse({"message":"Comment Created!"}, status=200)

    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({'comment':list(Comment.objects.values())}, status=200)
```

And I used the program called Httpie to give JSON POST request like so:

```
http -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment access_token="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImJlY2sifQ.2unop67pLHOshcGs385GwOvaZZW_J--TRNXyHI3gKNU" content="hello"
```

There is no problem with the token since this is the exact copy of the token give during the SignInView(which is in another app).

Below is the models.py file in the 'comment' app.

```
from django.db                  import models
from account.models   import Account

class Comment(models.Model):
    username    = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content     = models.TextField()
    created_time= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_time= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'comments'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username + ": " + self.content
```

However, when I send the POST request with the Httpie like above, I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /comment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/woohyunan/miniconda3/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/woohyunan/miniconda3/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/woohyunan/miniconda3/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/woohyunan/miniconda3/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/woohyunan/miniconda3/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/woohyunan/projects/Wecode/westagram/KillaGramz-backend/comment/views.py", line 19, in wrapper
    given_token     = json.loads(request.body)['access_token']
AttributeError: 'CommentView' object has no attribute 'body'
[20/May/2020 17:35:40] "POST /comment HTTP/1.1" 500 73224
```

I have been wondering what would cause the error. I wonder if there is no way to put the json request body into the decorator which would allow me to decode the token(the decoded version will be the username) so that I can see if it matches with the username in the database.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem!

```
def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

needs to be

```
def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```